# How to stop CI builds in Jenkins from accidentally publishing to release repository?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

Sometimes, the developers accidentally check in a version in POM without "SNAPSHOT" in it. This builds the Maven project and publishes the artifacts to release repository. How can I avoid this situation? I only want to publish build artifacts to release repository and not a CI build.

I thought about the following- but none of them is an easy one step solution

- Writing a pre-commit hook to check if version was checked in without SNAPSHOT by any one other than admin who is allowed to do a release build;
- Modify the Jenkins job to see if the build is a CI build; then grep for version and error out if the version is a not a SNAPSHOT version. For this I need to modify 100s of jobs.

Comment: what version control/branch strategy do you use? you could actually break the build if on `develop` the version is not a `SNAPSHOT` or vice-versa if in a release branch the version is not a release candidate and many other things simply via `pom.xml` configuration

Comment: There is an [enhancement request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-204) for the Maven Enforcer Plugin to enforce snapshot versions. It is currently unresolved but I'll work on it, it seems like a legitimate use case. This way, you could enforce a snapshot (and fail the build) if not in a release / deploy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good solution around this is to leverage the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/).

#### Update to 1.4.2

Starting with version 1.4.2 (not released yet, see the enhancement request [MENFORCER-204](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-204)), there is a new `requireSnapshotVersion` rule, which enforces that the project being built has a snapshot version.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-snapshot</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireSnapshotVersion/>
        </rules>
        <fail>${fail.if.release}</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

#### Write a custom rule

Up to version 1.4.1, there is no built-in rule to fail if the current project is a SNAPSHOT version, but we can still use the [`evaluateBeanshell`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/evaluateBeanshell.html) rule.

The idea is to make the build fail is the version is not a snapshot version by default. And when the current project is in a release, disable that rule.

For that, you can have the following in your POM:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-beanshell</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <evaluateBeanshell>
            <condition>"${project.version}".endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")</condition>
          </evaluateBeanshell>
        </rules>
        <fail>${fail.if.release}</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

What this does is executing a [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) script that evaluates the project's version. If it ends with `-SNAPSHOT` then the rule passes, otherwise, the rule fails and the build ends. Determining whether a version is a snapshot. (The strict rule for snapshots versions are [more complicated](http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/05/maven-code-how-to-detect-if-you-have-a-snapshot-version/) but this should cover all use cases). Therefore, such a rule will validate that the project being build has a SNAPSHOT version.

---

Both configurations above declares a Maven property as

```
<property>
  <fail.if.release>true</fail.if.release>
</property>
```

They will make your build fails when `mvn deploy` is run on a SNAPSHOT version, making sure no SNAPSHOT are accidently deployed to the release repository.

Then, the rule need to be disabled when a release is performed. For that, we can define a `release` profile to disable the defined rule:

```
<profile>
  <id>release</id>
  <properties>
    <fail.if.release>false</fail.if.release>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

and activate that profile on release with

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Prelease"
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Side note: looking at the website of BeanShell, I was quite shocked they used Comics Sans for the left side menu, there should be an adsBlocker addons like to block such font..

Comment: Can this be added to the company parent pom so that all projects follow the same rule? Or it is recommended that I add it to individual project parent pom only?

Comment: @user1164061 This could be very well added in a parent POM yes, to be shared among project.